# Identifying special characters in a column - Teradata

Tags: regex, teradata

I've a situation where some special characters entered into a column.

For Example:- "Special Character â€“ Standard".

The column legal values contains Alphabets and hyphen - symbol.

Any Help?

I am not able to get them through Equality operator.

Thanks

Comment: Try some `u` notation `"\u00E2\u20AC\u201C"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like  in below query.

[ ] in below query means any value place in that square baracets

A-Z means any aplhabet between A and Z

- is your - values as - has special meaning, it has to be escaped by \

^ in [ ] means it should not have any  of the above mentioned value. This gives all your special character values (as defined by you)

- indicates one or more value of special character value

i is for ignorecase

= 1 means true

.* means your variable may have other value along with special character values.

This query gives all the values where column you are interested

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE REGEXP_SIMILAR(columnname, '.*[^A-Z\-]+.*', 'i') = 1;
```

Comment: If I wanted to update the special characters how should I approach, regexp_replace(columnname,'â€“" ,"-") ??. I'm worried if the regex will identify those or not.

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE(columnname, [^A-Z\-], '-',1,0,i) or something like REGEXP_REPLACE(columnname, [â€]+, '-',1,0,i)

Comment: Probably more effective ``otranslate(columnname, 'â'||chr(9), '')``.